# React , I want to set count to localStorage

Tags: reactjs

I have like btn, bellow I have span - it will show and count how many times I clicked this like btn. When I reload page, numbers are still there, but if I will try to add more likes it will count from zero. Can you please show me why?
Thank you.

```
function ocko() {
  return (
    <article className='midleBox'>
      <Ocko/>
    </article>
  )
}

function Ocko () {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className='ms-3'>Ocko</h3>
      <img src={ockoImg} className='img' style={{width:'100px'}} alt="img"/>
      <div className='flexBox'>
         <LikesBox/>
         <HeartBox/>
         <Star/>
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const LikesBox = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0) 
    function clickHandler() {
      setCount(count+1) 
      localStorage.setItem('like', JSON.stringify(count))   // locStorage here
    }

  return(
    <article className='Liker'>
         <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill like" onClick={clickHandler}></i>
         <span > {localStorage.getItem('like')} </span>      // and here
    </article>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your initial state based on what is already in local storage

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem('like') || 0);
```

Also, instead of using local storage to display it, since you're keeping track in your own React state you can just use `count` directly

```
<span > {count} </span>
```